# Exiting application iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

When my application loads, using the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`i parse data from the internet to nsarrays. My question is, when the user exists the application by using the 'home' button, and then loads the application again how can the data be re-loaded? (because if the data does not reload - if there are any updates on websites, the new updates will not be seen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an applicationWillEnterForeground method to your app delegate. Load the data there, or start a thread to load it if you like.

You should probably also periodically check for new data even while the app remains open, because the user could go idle for a long time.

Comment: Excellent. One more question, how can i overlay the default image when the application loads? so it loads when the user enters the application again (After being in the foreground)

Comment: @spike lee Don't use comment sections to ask additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you shouldn't do anything which might block in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  If you are using synchronous NSURLConnection APIs there is a danger the OS might kill your app for taking too long to launch.  Best to either use the asynchronous/NSURLConnectionDelegate APIs or do the networking on a background thread and call back to the main thread when you need to update UI (UIKit does NOT like being called from background threads, as it is not thread safe. It might appear to work sometimes, but it will come back to bite you sooner or later).